# How do I allow users to authenticate with my REST API?

Tags: php, api, rest

I am trying to create a REST API for my next project. I think I understand most of the concepts, but am a little unsure about security. Obviously security is the one thing you don't want to get wrong even from the first release of production code.

I understand that REST is stateless, so instead of having a user log in and their session be stored on the server and restarted whenever they make a request, they send the server their unique API key and the server authenticates them on every request.

So how does a user logging into a system look "under the hood"? Is it something like:

1. The user enters their username and password
2. These are sent via POST (or PUT) to an API endpoint
3. If the credentials are valid, a unique API key is generated and returned to the client
4. If the credentials are not valid, an error is returned to the client

It is then the client's responsibility to store the API key and submit it with each request. This key is stored on the server in a database and used to identify the user and their permissions etc. on each request.

This sounds reasonable, but also breaks the true statelessness of the application because most requests require the initial "make me an API key" request to have been sent.

Thanks in advance for helping me understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GroupMe](http://dev.groupme.com)'s API for example uses a token-based approach to authenticating users of their API (this allows users of their API to create scripts to call the API on their behalf).

In order to successfully make API calls, I (as the user of the API) had to sign in and create an application, which provided me with an Access Token (see image).

[image]

This access token (in the case of groupme) is what I had to include with all requests in order for the request to be successful. The format may differ depending on who's API you are using but in the case of groupme, it looks like this:

```
https://api.groupme.com/v3/PAGE_TO_CALL?token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

This would allow the GroupMe API to identify me and perform whatever action I had specified. This access token is like my username and password, whoever has it will be able to make API calls as me, including any scripts I create...

If you are interested in **creating** your own REST API, I would look into [this](http://www.andrewhavens.com/posts/20/beginners-guide-to-creating-a-rest-api/) article, specifically the last section on creating a token-based authentication method that other users could use to authenticate with your API.

Here is the most relevant excerpt:

> **API authentication**
>   In normal web applications, handling authentication is usually handled by accepting a username and password, and saving the user ID in the session. The user's browser saves a cookie with ID of the session. When the user visits a page on the site that requires authentication, the browser sends the cookie, the app looks up the session by the ID (if it hasn't expired), and since the user ID was saved in the session, the user is allowed to view the page.
>   With an API, using sessions to keep track of users is not necessarily the best approach. Sometimes, your users may want to access the API directly, other times the user may way to authorize another application to access the API on their behalf.
>   The solution to this is to use token based authentication. The user logs in with their username and password and the application responds with a unique token that the user can use for future requests. This token can be passed onto the application so that the user can revoke that token later if they choose to deny that application further access.
>   There is a standard way of doing this that has become very popular. It's called OAuth. Specifically, version 2 of the OAuth standard. There are a lot of great resources online for implementing OAuth so I would say that is outside the scope of this tutorial. If you are using Ruby, there are some great libraries that handle most of the work for you, like OmniAuth.

Comment: Okay so you mean instead of "logging in", you had to manually request an access token from their system to use when making requests to their API. You said you had to sign in to create an application, and I assume their own website interacts with their API. How does that sign-in process work with their own system? I hope my question is a little clearer.

Comment: what do you mean sign-in process? are you referring to using the access token to authenticate with their API, or signing into dev.groupme.com to create the application and get the access token in the first place?

Comment: Where you signed in to dev.groupme.com in the first place

Comment: Are you wondering how the back-end of that works? sorry, I'm a little slow to understand...

Comment: No I apologise for not being clear enough. Yes that's what I'm asking about though. How their (or Facebook's / Google's etc.) own applications allow a user to sign in and then use functions within the application which make REST requests. The users in this context are not trying to use the API directly as they (probably) are not software engineers and don't know how any of this works. But I want to know how it all works as I'm trying to replicate this in my own REST API and applications.

Comment: so you're trying to create your own REST API and want to know how to allow a user to sign in and create an access token/API key etc.

Comment: I was actually typing up my own answer to this, but I think I misunderstood your question as well. Perhaps this is still incorrect, but are you asking how websites and web applications are able to do things like *retrieving notifications* and *updating newsfeeds* automatically using hidden, backend API calls without refreshing or redirecting the page? I may be entirely incorrect about my understanding of what you are trying to ask, but seeing as you said "they probably are not software engineers," I assume you aren't building this API for other developers to utilize.

Comment: Ah yes I remember reading about OAuth but it was a while ago and I forgot that it is used for this sort of thing. Thanks for the help and the link to the article!

Comment: no problem! glad i could understand your question and be of assistance! Ironically, I was actually considering making an API for my iOS apps to interact with my website so my answer actually helps me as well!

Comment: also, @BenGuest you could try googling "create a REST API" or similar, thats how i got to that article (i think it was one of the first results). other results in a similar search may help you.